# Calculate average in bash with more than 3 decimals

Tags: bash, awk, decimal, average

I am trying to calculate the average of some numbers in a file, in bash. I know `awk` does that perfectly with

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print "Average: " s/NR}' file
```

but it's only giving me 3 decimals output. While that is enough in some cases, I need 7 decimals . How can I do that?

Comment: if any answer helps you kindly consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. And possibly also upvote the useful answers

Answer (score 1):

When printing the value, use `printf` with an appropriate format string:

```
awk '{ s += $1 } END { printf("%.7f\n", s/NR) }' file
```

Comment: thank you very much . it worked perfectly! did not expected such a fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum/FNR}' OFMT="%0.9g"  Input_file
```